# Changing hotkey for keyboard layout in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, keyboard-layout

The hotkey for changing keyboard layouts in XP are bound only to <kbd>Alt+Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Shift</kbd>.

Is is possible to enable a hotkey toggle, like holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to toggle the alternate layout, and releasing it to toggle it back?

Comment: check out [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)

Comment: @Raystafarian, not very helpful. Care to at least post a specific script to do what he wants instead of just linking to what amounts to a **programming language**? What’s next, posting a link to the C++ page on Wikipedia?

Comment: @Synetech That's why it's a **comment** and not an _answer_, OP can check it out and see if it's _a utility_ the OP wants to mess around with. _Awesome comment, though! Really helps the OP out too!_

Comment: @Synetech: Let me correct that for you... **macro scripting language**, so completely valid and welcome comment. It's not really hard to make it, doing some C++ programming is a joke comparison... :/

Comment: I was being sarcastic. Linking to a page that discusses dealing this or a similar issue with AutoHotkey is one thing, but simply mentioning it in general then leaving the asker to figure it out for themselves… Not everyone who has a computer problem is a programmer, and no, a scripting language isn’t any better; programming is programming no matter how hard or easy. If you look at the question again, you’ll see that they’re looking for a command or OS interface.